# Passing command line arguments

Tags: c++, command-line, vector

Okay I have updated my code a little, but I am still not exactly sure how to use the vector of command line arguments that I pass. I tried to set it up like the code I have below, but it wont compile. It gives me the error that it cannot find argc and argv:

1>c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\cplusplustwo\cplusplustwo\application.h(32) : error C2065: 'argc' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\cplusplustwo\cplusplustwo\application.h(32) : error C2065: 'argv' : undeclared identifier

main.cpp

```
#include "application.h"

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    vector<string> args(argv, argv + argc);
    return app.run(args);    
}
```

application.h

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "time.h"
using namespace std;



class application{
private:
    //Variables
    boost::regex expression;
    string line;
    string pat;
    string replace;
    int lineNumber;
    char date[9];
    char time[9];


    void commandLine(vector<string> args){
        string  expression="";    // Expression
        string  textReplace="";   // Replacement Text
        string  inputFile="";     // Input File
        string  outputFile="";    // Output Directory
        int optind=1;
        // decode arguments
        for(vector<string>::iterator i = args.begin(); i != args.end(); ++i){
            while ((optind < argc) && (argv[optind][0]=='-')) {
                string sw = argv[optind];
                if (*i == "-e") {
                    optind++;
                    expression = argv[optind];
                }
                else if (*i == "-t") {
                    optind++;
                    textReplace = argv[optind];
                }
                else if (*i == "-i") {
                    optind++;
                    inputFile = argv[optind];
                }
                else if (*i == "-o") {
                    optind++;
                    outputFile = argv[optind];
                }
                else{
                    cout << "Unknown switch: " 
                        << argv[optind] << "Please enter one of the correct parameters:\n" 
                        << "-e + \"expression\"\n-t + \"replacement Text\"\n-i + \"Input File\"\n-o + \"Onput File\"\n";
                    optind++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Functions
    void getExpression(){
        cout << "Expression: ";
        getline(cin,pat);
        try{
            expression = pat;
        }
        catch(boost::bad_expression){
            cout << pat << " is not a valid regular expression\n";
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    void boostMatch(){
        //Define replace {FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY!!! REMOVE BEFORE SUBMITTING!!
        replace = "";
        _strdate_s(date);
        _strtime_s(time);
        lineNumber = 0;
        //Files to open
        //Input Files
        ifstream in("files/trff292010.csv");
            if(!in) cerr << "no file\n";
        //Output Files
        ofstream newFile("files/NEWtrff292010.csv");
        ofstream copy("files/ORIGtrff292010.csv");
        ofstream report("files/REPORT.dat", ios.app);
        lineNumber++;
        while(getline(in,line)){
            lineNumber++;
            boost::smatch matches;
            copy << line << '\n';
            if (regex_search(line, matches, expression)){
                for (int i = 0; i<matches.size(); ++i){
                    report << "Time: " << time << "Date: " << date << '\n'
                        << "Line " << lineNumber <<": " << line << '\n';
                    newFile << boost::regex_replace(line, expression, replace) << "\n";

                }
            }else{
                newFile << line << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

public:
    void run(vector<string> args){
        commandLine(vector<string> args);
        getExpression();
        boostMatch();
    }
};
```

**ORIGINAL POST**

I want to pass command line arguments out of main. This is homework for an advanced C++ class.  I need to pass the command line with a vector and I am not sure if I am doing everything correctly. Would I pass it into a vector like I did? Also is there a copy() command you can use to copy the command line arguments into a vector rather than pushback?

```
main.cpp

#include "application.h"

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    vector<string> args;
    application app;
    for (int i=1;i<argc;i++){
        args.push_back(argv[i]);
    }
    app.run(args);
    return(0);
}
```

application.h

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include "time.h"
    using namespace std;

class application{
private:
    //Variables
    boost::regex expression;
    string line;
    string pat;
    string replace;
    int lineNumber;
    char date[9];
    char time[9];


    void commandLine(vector<string> args){
        string  expression="";    // Expression
        string  textReplace="";   // Replacement Text
        string  inputFile="";     // Input File
        string  outputFile="";    // Output Directory
        int optind=1;
        // decode arguments
        for(vector<string>::iterator i = args.begin(); i != args.end(); ++i){
            while ((optind < argc) && (argv[optind][0]=='-')) {
                string sw = argv[optind];
                if (*i == "-e") {
                    optind++;
                    expression = argv[optind];
                }
                else if (*i == "-t") {
                    optind++;
                    textReplace = argv[optind];
                }
                else if (*i == "-i") {
                    optind++;
                    inputFile = argv[optind];
                }
                else if (*i == "-o") {
                    optind++;
                    outputFile = argv[optind];
                }
                else{
                    cout << "Unknown switch: " 
                        << argv[optind] << "Please enter one of the correct parameters:\n" 
                        << "-e + \"expression\"\n-t + \"replacement Text\"\n-i + \"Input File\"\n-o + \"Onput File\"\n";
                    optind++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Functions
    void getExpression(){
        cout << "Expression: ";
        getline(cin,pat);
        try{
            expression = pat;
        }
        catch(boost::bad_expression){
            cout << pat << " is not a valid regular expression\n";
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    void boostMatch(){
        //Define replace {FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY!!! REMOVE BEFORE SUBMITTING!!
        replace = "";
        _strdate_s(date);
        _strtime_s(time);
        lineNumber = 0;
        //Files to open
        //Input Files
        ifstream in("files/trff292010.csv");
            if(!in) cerr << "no file\n";
        //Output Files
        ofstream newFile("files/NEWtrff292010.csv");
        ofstream copy("files/ORIGtrff292010.csv");
        ofstream report("files/REPORT.dat", ios.app);
        lineNumber++;
        while(getline(in,line)){
            lineNumber++;
            boost::smatch matches;
            copy << line << '\n';
            if (regex_search(line, matches, expression)){
                for (int i = 0; i<matches.size(); ++i){
                    report << "Time: " << time << "Date: " << date << '\n'
                        << "Line " << lineNumber <<": " << line << '\n';
                    newFile << boost::regex_replace(line, expression, replace) << "\n";

                }
            }else{
                newFile << line << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

public:
    void run(vector<string> args){
        commandLine(vector<string> args);
        getExpression();
        boostMatch();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd just write:

```
vector<string> args(argv + 1, argv + argc + !argc);
```

This will exclude `argv[0]`, but in a way that's robust even if `argc == 0` (possible under Linux, and maybe other OSs too).

Comment: is that how you would right the original vector in main before passing in the arguments?

Comment: @shinjuo: That constructs a vector, `args`, initialising it with all the command-line arguments in one shot. (I'm sorry, I didn't know how to read your comment very well.)

Comment: just to make sure I understand you correctly, I can delete all the pushback in main and just use this?

Comment: @shinjuo: Yep, exactly. Though, don't forget, if you want to exclude `argv[0]`, you must arrange to do this yourself.

Comment: @shinjuo: For example, you could do: `vector<string> args(argv + 1, argv + argc)`, although, if `argc == 0` (possible under Linux, and maybe other OSs too), then you invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: does it matter to exclude argv[0]?

Comment: This will only really be ran on my windows machine

Comment: @shinjuo: The code you posted does exclude `argv[0]`, which normally holds the program name. On Windows, `argc` will never be 0, so don't worry about it: `argv + 1, argv + argc` will work well enough.

Comment: Re your update question about not compiling, add `#include <vector>` to your `application.h`.

Comment: Sorry I did not put the error code. It gives me that it cannot find the identifier argc and argv

Answer (score 2):

argv and argc are parameters passed to main.  In your function you should be using args[i] and args.length()

Comment: I am not sure I know where you are talking about using those?

Comment: Within your application methods use the args vector rather than the argc and argv variables.

Answer (score 1):

`application::commandLine()` takes `args` as a parameter, but it refers to `argc` and `argv`, which are not in scope. If you look at the actual error message from the compiler, it should contain a filename and line number that point you directly at the location of the error. When asking for help with an error message, please post the actual error message instead of paraphrasing it.